# gcc doesn't run even after installation

Tags: gcc, ubuntu-15.10

I am new to ubuntu and running ubuntu 15.10. I was trying to run a C code and got the following error.[image]

so I installed it with the given command and now it says:

[image]

how to do i run it? New to this so bear with me.

EDIT: the output for `echo $PATH`is below:[image]

When i run the command `dpkg --listfiles gcc | grep bin/gcc` i get the following output [image]

Comment: @DmitriChubarov what do i do after that?

Comment: @DmitriChubarov could write the entire solution at once?

Comment: I am just guessing. It looks like something is wrong with your machine. My first guess was that you had a mangled PATH. My second guess is something happened to your gcc installation. I suggest you check if `/usr/bin/gcc` exists and is executable.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov would you recommend a reinstallation of the OS? Much thanks

Comment: I have listed some more steps in the form of an answer. Hope it will be something that can be easily fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something is wrong with your machine. There are a few things to check if things go wrong.

#### 1. Check the `PATH` variable

First you need to check that the PATH variable contains the system managed installation directories, such as `/usr/bin`.

Type `echo $PATH` on the console and make sure that it contains a sequence of paths delimited by `:` that contains `/usr/bin`, as well as `/bin`

#### 2. Check if the package files are present

Type `dpkg --verify gcc ; echo $?`. If the package files are present, this command should print out `0`.

```bash
:~> dpkg --verify gcc ; echo $?
0
```

Type `dpkg --listfiles gcc` to get a list of files that were installed when `gcc` was installed. Check if `/usr/bin/gcc` is on the list. You could use `grep` to filter output.

```bash
:~> dpkg --listfiles gcc | grep bin/gcc              
/usr/bin/gcc-ranlib
/usr/bin/gcc-nm
/usr/bin/gcc-ar
/usr/bin/gcc
```

#### 3. Check if there are any conflicts or missing dependencies

Use `dpkg --status` command.

```bash
:~> dpkg --status gcc    
Package: gcc
Status: install ok installed
...
Conflicts: gcc-doc (<< 1:2.95.3)
Description: GNU C compiler
 This is the GNU C compiler, a fairly portable optimizing compiler for C.
 .
 This is a dependency package providing the default GNU C compiler.
```

Here the command says that the documentation is outdated or missing for the compiler.

#### 4. Check that the file `/usr/bin/gcc` has correct permissions

It should be executable

```bash
:~> ls -l /usr/bin/gcc                 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Feb 25  2015 /usr/bin/gcc -> gcc-4.9
```

In Ubuntu `/usr/bin/gcc` is a symbolic link to the correct version of the compiler. Check that the link is valid.

#### 5. Check that the package that contains compiler binary is installed

See what package provides the compiler binary:

```bash
:~> dpkg -S /usr/bin/gcc-4.9
gcc-4.9: /usr/bin/gcc-4.9
```

Repeat steps 2-4 for the package `gcc-4.9`.

#### 6. Try to run it

Try running the executable with the full path:

```bash
:~> /usr/bin/gcc     
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
:~> /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 
gcc-4.9: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

If any of the above steps fail, this could provide a further hint on the cause of the problem.

Comment: while going through the steps(1-3 showed the correct results) , i failed on STep 4, the error it shows is "cannot access /usr/bin/gcc: No such file or directory"

Comment: @prameshshakya  Do you have `/usr/bin`?  If you have `file` utility, `file /usr/bin` should return `directory`

Comment: yes i do have the directory but the gcc folder is missing for some reason, is it okay if i take this to a chat? the site is suggesting so.
EDIT::
there are gcc files but no gcc folder, is there supposed to be a gcc folder?

Comment: @prameshshakya Yes chat is ok